# Restrict access to a MediaWiki page to specific users

Tags: mediawiki

I have some pages which I want to restrict access to specific users, i.e, I want user A and user B only to view this page. How can this be done? Do I need additional extensions or it can be done through `LocalSettings.php` for example?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [preventing access](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access)?

Comment: Yes I read it and by default MediaWiki does not work like that so I though there might be extensions that help achieve that.

Comment: There are. But the [warning](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Restrict_viewing_of_certain_specific_pages) on that page applies. MediaWiki was not written in a way that would make such access management easy or robust. If ilegitimate view access would cause big problems for you, you probably don't want to use MediaWiki.

Comment: Well maybe it is too late for us to ask this, but do you know any alternatives with such access management?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with other wiki software, sorry.

Comment: I found this and it is true MediaWiki does have limited access control https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_software (Wiki page comparing wiki software, wikiception :D )

Answer (score 1):

You could try this extension: [Extension:AccessControl](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AccessControl). I've not deployed it to my wiki sites, but a quick read of the pages suggests it might be what you're looking for.

Note though that as [Tgr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/323407/tgr) covered in the comments above, Mediawiki is not intended to operate like this, so the extension could be fundamentally flawed in its implementation. Practise due diligence if you try to deploy any 3rd party extensions. Alternatively, look into alternative CMSs that handle access control as a core feature.